# Update progress bar from for loop

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a progress bar, i want to update the value from for loop equally 
how can i have equal data update?

example if the count of the loop is 10 or if the count is 1000 
how can i automate this?

FYI, the minimum value of the progress bar is 0 and the maximum is 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide whatever you current value is (let's call it x) by the maximum value and then multiple the result by 100.

```
double progress = (x / max) * 100;
```

Be careful however, if x and max are ints then you will end up doing integer division rather than floating point division. You may need to cast one or both to a double or float in that case.

Comment: @Joey: Yes, that's why I mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: To avoid truncation use `100 * x / max`.

Answer (score 5):

You can adjust the maximum of the progress bar to match your data size, or you can scale accordingly:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  // do something
  progressBar1.Value = i * progressBar1.Maximum / count;
  Application.DoEvents();
}
```